# How to deploy any R package on Rconnect? I want to deploy cerebroApp on Rconnect server but don't know how to deploy it

Tags: r

CererbroApp is built using Rshiny. To run cerebroApp, we just need to type launchCerebro() in the console, and then it opens in a new window. Can anyone help how to deploy this app on the Rconnect server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to answer based on the setup I am used to.

In order to deploy in RStudio Connect from RStudio Server (or Desktop) you need to go to Tools -> Global Options -> Publishing where you need to set up your RStudio Connect connection. [image: RStudioPublishingWindow]

Then you pass the URL where RStudio Connect is deployed and authenticate yourself. Once you are connected to RStudio Connect, you can deploy apps programatically (see package `rsconnect` (in particular `rsconnect::deployApp()`) or for interactive deployment if you have any app.R, ui.R, server.R or global.R file that RStudio recognises as a Shiny app you will see the Publication button in the upper right side of your RStudio window:
[image: Publication button]

Click publish, follow the instructions ... and off you go!